# Selection of Sensor API on Win10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, sensors

I found there are two ways to use the Sensor API:

1.Windows.Devices.Sensors, like [LightSensor class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.sensors.lightsensor.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#)

2.[Traditional Sensor API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318953(v=vs.85).aspx)

My device is Win10, and I knew the first method(Windows.Devices.Sensors) is modest to use; However, it need to use Universal Windows Platform(VS2015), but I don't want to use the UWP in this case.

I want to know whether the second method(Traditional Sensor API) can be used in the Win10?

Thanks!

Comment: MFC tag is useless. I think you are looking for Desktop APIs, which is the second link you posted.

Comment: Thanks Barmak! I've removed the MFC tag.

Comment: Have you found out if #2 works for Windows 10?