# Getting sensor data on Windows 10 without UWP

Tags: c++, windows-10, sensors

I noticed that the following duplicate question on [Selection of Sensor API on Win10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232224/selection-of-sensor-api-on-win10) has never been answered, so I want to readdress this.

I need to access the sensor data on Windows 10 without using UWP (for compatibility with Unity etc.).

For the old Sensor API at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sensorsapi/about-the-sensor-api, it states that the supported OS is Windows 7. Nonetheless, will this still work on Windows 10?  If not, what are some non-UWP Windows 10 sensor APIs that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the docs actually say the "**Minimum supported client**" is Windows 7. Windows 10 still has a `SensorApi.dll`, so you might give it a try.

Note that UWP didn't exist in Windows 7, when these APIs were published. It looks  like a normal COM API.